# how can i track download progress after app is did become active from background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, download

i have a problem described in title. you may see source code in my repository (https://github.com/Hudayberdyyev/custom_download_manager) . i will try to briefly explain the problem. I am trying to write a download manager based on this repo (https://github.com/r-plus/HLSion). and basically it consists of 3 parts:

1. SessionManager (Which managed all of sessions)
2. HLSData (HLSData model which initialized same as the code below. it is like an intermediary between the session manager )

```
public convenience init(url: URL, options: [String: Any]? = nil, name: String) {
        let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: options)
        self.init(asset: urlAsset, description: name)
}
```

3. AssetStore (It's managed HLSData.plist file. Which contain name and path of each download session).

this is how the start of downloads is implemented:

```
var sources = [HLSData]()
@objc func startDownloadButtonTapped() {
        print(#function)
        let hlsData = sources[0]
        switch hlsData.state {
        case .notDownloaded:
            hlsData.download { (percent) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("percent = \(percent)")
                    self.percentLabel.text = "\(percent)"
                }
            }.finish { (relativePath) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("download completed relative path = \(relativePath)")
                }
            }.onError { (error) in
                print("Error finish. \(error)")
            }
        case .downloading:
            print("State is downloading")
            break
        case .downloaded:
            print(hlsData.localUrl ?? "localURL is nil")
        }
}
```

Before tapping state is ***notDownloaded***. respectively app is start download when the button tapped and state is changed to ***downloading***.
Everything is works fine and progress tracked well. But when i go to the background and return back to app, state is still keep of downloading, but progress closure doesn't work anymore. How can i restore or reset this closures for tracking progress. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On doing some tests, I feel there is a bug in `iOS 12 and below` with the `AVAssetDownloadDelegate`

When doing some tests, I noticed the following when trying to download media over HLS using `AVAssetDownloadTask`:

**iOS 13 and above**

1. When going into the background, the download continues
2. When coming into the foreground from the background, the `AVAssetDownloadDelegate` still triggers `assetDownloadTask didLoad totalTimeRangesLoaded` and the progress can be updated
3. After suspending or quitting an app, reinitializing an `AVAssetDownloadURLSession` with the same `URLSessionConfiguration identifier`, the download resumes automatically from where it last left off

**iOS 12 and below**

Everything still almost holds true except point 2, for some reason the `assetDownloadTask didLoad totalTimeRangesLoaded` no longer gets triggered when coming into the foreground from the background and so the progress no longer gets updated.

One workaround I got was from this answer `https://stackoverflow.com/a/55847387/1619193` was that in the past, downloads had to be resumed manually after the app was suspended for `AVAssetDownloadTask` by providing it a location to the partially downloaded file on disk.

As per the documentation:

> AVAssetDownloadTask provides the ability to resume previously stopped
> downloads under certain circumstances. To do so, simply instantiate a
> new AVAssetDownloadTask with an AVURLAsset instantiated with a file
> NSURL pointing to the partially downloaded bundle with the desired
> download options, and the download will continue restoring any
> previously downloaded data.

Interestingly, you cannot find this on the official documentation anymore and also it seems like setting the `destinationURL` has been deprecated so it seems like there has been some refactoring in how things work.

My solution:

1. Subscribe to the `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification` notification
2. In the call back for the `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification`, check if the device is running iOS 12 and below
3. If it does, cancel the current `AVAssetDownloadTask`
4. This should trigger the `AVAssetDownloadDelegate` callback `assetDownloadTask didFinishDownloadingTo` which will give you the location of the partially downloaded file
5. Reconfigure the `AVAssetDownloadTask` but do not configure it with the HLS url, instead configure it with the URL to the partially downloaded asset
6. Resume the download and the progress `AVAssetDownloadDelegate` will seem to start firing again

You can download an example of this [here](https://github.com/shawn-frank/HLSDownloader)

Here are some small snippets of the above steps:

```
private let downloadButton = UIButton(type: .system)

private let downloadTaskIdentifier = "com.mindhyve.HLSDOWNLOADER"

private var backgroundConfiguration: URLSessionConfiguration?
private var assetDownloadURLSession: AVAssetDownloadURLSession!
private var downloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // UI configuration left out intentionally
    subscribeToNotifications()
    initializeDownloadSession()
}

private func initializeDownloadSession()
{
    // This will create a new configuration if the identifier does not exist
    // Otherwise, it will reuse the existing identifier which is how a download
    // task resumes
    backgroundConfiguration
        = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: downloadTaskIdentifier)
    
    // Resume will happen automatically when this configuration is made
    assetDownloadURLSession
        = AVAssetDownloadURLSession(configuration: backgroundConfiguration!,
                                    assetDownloadDelegate: self,
                                    delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
}

private func resumeDownloadTask()
{
    var sourceURL = getHLSSourceURL(.large)
    
    // Now Check if we have any previous download tasks to resume
    if let destinationURL = destinationURL
    {
        sourceURL = destinationURL
    }
    
    if let sourceURL = sourceURL
    {
        let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: sourceURL)
        
        downloadTask = assetDownloadURLSession.makeAssetDownloadTask(asset: urlAsset,
                                                                     assetTitle: "Movie",
                                                                     assetArtworkData: nil,
                                                                     options: nil)
        
        downloadTask.resume()
    }
}

func cancelDownloadTask()
{
    downloadTask.cancel()
}

private func getHLSSourceURL(_ size: HLSSampleSize) -> URL?
{
    if size == .large
    {
        return URL(string: "https://video.film.belet.me/45505/480/ff27c84a-6a13-4429-b830-02385592698b.m3u8")
    }
    
    return URL(string: "https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/bipbop_4x3_variant.m3u8")
}

// MARK: INTENTS
@objc
private func downloadButtonTapped()
{
    print("\(downloadButton.titleLabel!.text!) tapped")
    
    if downloadTask != nil,
       downloadTask.state == .running
    {
        cancelDownloadTask()
    }
    else
    {
        resumeDownloadTask()
    }
}

@objc
private func didEnterForeground()
{
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) { return }
    
    // In iOS 12 and below, there seems to be a bug with AVAssetDownloadDelegate.
    // It will not give you progress when coming from the background so we cancel
    // the task and resume it and you should see the progress in maybe 5-8 seconds
    if let downloadTask = downloadTask
    {
        downloadTask.cancel()
        initializeDownloadSession()
        resumeDownloadTask()
    }
}

private func subscribeToNotifications()
{
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(didEnterForeground),
                                           name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
                                           object: nil)
}

// MARK: AVAssetDownloadDelegate
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                task: URLSessionTask,
                didCompleteWithError error: Error?)
{
    guard error != nil else
    {
        // download complete, do what you want
        return
    }
    
    // something went wrong, handle errors
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                assetDownloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask,
                didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL)
{
    // Save the download path of the task to resume downloads
    destinationURL = location
}
```

If something seems out of place, I recommend checking out the full working example [here](https://github.com/shawn-frank/HLSDownloader)